# Where have all the downloads gone?

Tags: ps3, ps4, psn

I'm having trouble listing all my downloaded/purchased games/demos/extras. My "Downloads" list only lists the lasts 10/15 items I've purchased.  If I search a game I see the "Purchased" icon and can download it again, but it does not show on my "Downloads" list, which makes it troublesome to re-download stuff like the themes.

Why is my list only showing me last ten purchased items, and how can I get it to show everything like it used to?

I have updated the store, the PS3 and PS4; deactivated and reactivated both, and the last PS3 I had had irreparable damage to the mother board.

Comment: While it may not answer your question, this appears to be a bug in the PSN system. Reading on [this](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-Support/View-Downloads-only-shows-last-18-items-in-PS3/td-p/46170390) PSN support, you should be able to access your downloads through *Account Management > Transaction Management > Download List*

Comment: You should just be able to go to *library > purchased*, which will show everything you've gotten from the store ever, even if it was free.

Comment: Great, happy to mark it as correct if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Library and then Purchased to show all your content.